# difficulty setting up c# "friend" relationship with InternalsVisibleTo

Tags: c#

I am trying to setup a friend relationship from a class called MyObject to MemoryManager.  Meaning, I want MemoryManager to be able to access all protected elements in MyObject (so that it can do its job).

I have in one file:

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    public class MemoryManager
    {
        public int someMethod(MyObject o) {
           int k = o._protectedCalculation();
        }
    }
}
```

And in another file:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("my_namespace.MemoryManager")]

namespace my_namespace
{
    public class MyObject
    {
        protected int a;
        protected int b;
        protected int _protectedCalculation() { return a+b };
    }
}
```

I figured that this would allow MemoryManager to acces o._protectedMember, however this gives me the error:

```
my_namespace.MyObject._protectedCalculation() is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or does InternalsVisibleTo not do what I am hoping it does?

Comment: [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) gives a different *assembly* access to members marked `internal` (which are normally only visible inside their own assembly). It doesn't do anything regarding `protected`.

Comment: A "memory manager" class might be better suited to simply using reflection to access private/protected members. But you know that C# already manages memory for you, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`protected` is not the same as VB.NET's "`Friend`". Since the attribute is named `InternalsVisibleTo`, you should mark your member as `internal`.

In case you want it to be both `internal` and `protected`, you can use `protected internal`:

```
protected internal int _protectedCalculation() { return a+b };
```

Answer (score 1):

`InternalsVisibleTo` works with assemblies, not with classes or namespaces. If your classes are in different assemblies, you need to use the assembly name inside the attribute for it to work, like this:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssembly")]
```

Also, as some people have commented, you need to mark the members with the `internal` modifier, not with the `protected` one. Protected allows visibility to inheriting classes, while `internal` means that the member is visible across the whole assembly or to friend assemblies.